# Arranging two divs beside one div without overflowing

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie into web designing and I am already stuck. I am using Joomla to make a website and I am trying to make divs as shown below

[image]

I saw codes that could do this by setting width in %.

What I want to do is

```
• Div 1 can be as wide as its contents (picture mostly) <br>
• Div 2 is the header and is usually single line <br>
• Div 3 is the body and no matter how long it is, it should not come below Div 1. So basically Div 1 should be as long as the container.
```

This is probably a very silly question but I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Not a silly question, welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not allow the sidebar to be as wide as the content. If you have images, make images fill a defined width (even if you have it be a proportion of the page, in %). The risk with this is that if your image is wider it will affect your page design.

Here is a quick example of what you are trying to achieve:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div{
            display:block;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        #div1{
            float:left; 
            width:30%; 
            padding: 1%; 
            border:1px solid black
        }
        #div2{
            float:right; 
            width: 64%; 
            padding:1%; 
            border:1px solid red
        }
        #div3{
            float:right; 
            width: 64%; 
            padding:1%; 
            border:1px solid yellow
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div1">div 1<br />This is your sidebar</div>
    <div id="div2">div 2 <br /> This is your header line</div>
    <div id="div3">div 3 <br />This is your body container</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define width of your div's in px or em as you want multiple div section across your web page.In initial stages of web development, adjust everything in % is quite tricky.

For alignment you can refer **float** property of css http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

With percentages: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEcse
**percentage-based lay-out**

```
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {padding: 20px 10px;}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.main {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.header h1 {margin: 0;}
.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

For images to take the full available space you can do:

```
img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

**Pixel lay-out**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGapt

**CSS**

```
 html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 990px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner {padding: 20px 10px;}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.main {
  float: right;
  width: 700px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.header h1 {margin: 0;}
.content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="left">I am the left side.</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>I am the header</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="content">I am the content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```